# White page wamp Win Server 2008 project Codeigniter with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, windows-server-2008, wamp

I have copied my project in windows server 2008 (wampserver 2.4). I added rewrite_module but it does not work, it shows white page. My project works on Ubuntu and Mac (mamp).

```
.htaccess

#For Mac Mamp
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

#For Ubuntu
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have other Codeigniter projects on the same server and they work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting rewrite base as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foldername
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It not works, I have changed my .htaccess and restarted all services.

Comment: I have other Codeigniter projects on the same server and they work.

Comment: Php driver for sql server

Answer (score 0):

I am using sql server. I changed the driver to sqlsrv.